# How can I get VIM to maintain the creation date for a file? (OS X)

Tags: vim, ls

So whenever I save a file in VIM on OS X, it seems to overwrite the entire thing instead of updating it.

If I run `ls -tU` I can see that the creation date changes and it does indeed update to the last modified on the GUI. (OS X unlike other UNIX variants does maintain a file creation date)

Is there a quick fix for this?

Answer (score 4):

`:help 'backupcopy'` says:

```
                        *'backupcopy'* *'bkc'*
'backupcopy' 'bkc'  string  (Vi default for Unix: "yes", otherwise: "auto")
            global
            {not in Vi}
    When writing a file and a backup is made, this option tells how it's
    done.  This is a comma separated list of words.

    The main values are:
    "yes"   make a copy of the file and overwrite the original one
    "no"    rename the file and write a new one
    "auto"  one of the previous, what works best
```

It looks like just setting `'backupcopy'` to "yes" should get you what you're after. I.e. put this in your .vimrc:

```
set backupcopy=yes
```